# AWK or Sed to sort fields of the content within each line,

Tags: text, awk, sed

I need to sort fields (The delimiter is the comma. ) of the content within each line, 
I am not sure how can I do this, 
Some lines are ok, they start with DisplayName, others do not as they start with DisplayVersion

For example:

Input:

```
  DisplayVersion; 1.0.204,    DisplayName; Citrix Online Launcher
  DisplayName; Microsoft Automated Troubleshooting Services Shim
  DisplayVersion; 3.5.30729,    DisplayName; Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1
  DisplayName; Hotfix for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 (KB958484),    DisplayVersion; 1
  DisplayName; Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 (KB963707),    DisplayVersion; 1
  DisplayVersion; 5.2.3790.1164,    DisplayName; Windows Resource Kit Tools - SubInAcl.exe
  DisplayVersion; 1.0.1361.27800,    DisplayName; Windows Resource Kit Tools - GPInventory.exe
  DisplayVersion; 9.0.10.29005,    DisplayName; VMware Tools
```

Expected Output

```
  DisplayName; Citrix Online Launcher,DisplayVersion; 1.0.204
  DisplayName; Microsoft Automated Troubleshooting Services Shim
  DisplayName; Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1,DisplayVersion; 3.5.30729
  DisplayName; Hotfix for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 (KB958484),DisplayVersion; 1
  DisplayName; Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 (KB963707),DisplayVersion; 1
  DisplayName; Windows Resource Kit Tools - SubInAcl.exe,DisplayVersion; 5.2.3790.1164
  DisplayName; VMware Tools,DisplayVersion; 9.0.10.29005
```

Comment: it is not clear what you mean, give at least an algorithm of the logic underlying this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With gawk:

```
gawk -F ', +' -v OFS=, '{ split($0, a); asort(a); for(i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) { $i = a[i] } } 1' filename
```

That is:

```
{                              # in every line:
  split($0, a)                 # make an array of the fields
  asort(a)                     # sort the array
  for(i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) {   # put the fields back
    $i = a[i]
  }
}
1                              # print the result.
```

`asort` is not part of POSIX, so you need GNU awk for this.

Comment: You can replace `delete a
  for(i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) {
    a[i] = $i
  }` with just `split($0,a)`.

Comment: Oh, true. That is nicer, so I put it in. I chucked out the `n` variable while I was at it, since `n == NF`.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk 4.* for built in sorting:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="\\s*,\\s*"; OFS=","; PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_str_asc" }
{
    split($0,flds)
    fldNr=0
    for (i in flds) {
        printf "%s%s", flds[i], (++fldNr<NF?OFS:ORS)
    }
}
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
DisplayName; Citrix Online Launcher,DisplayVersion; 1.0.204
DisplayName; Microsoft Automated Troubleshooting Services Shim
DisplayName; Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1,DisplayVersion; 3.5.30729
DisplayName; Hotfix for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 (KB958484),DisplayVersion; 1
DisplayName; Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 (KB963707),DisplayVersion; 1
DisplayName; Windows Resource Kit Tools - SubInAcl.exe,DisplayVersion; 5.2.3790.1164
DisplayName; Windows Resource Kit Tools - GPInventory.exe,DisplayVersion; 1.0.1361.27800
DisplayName; VMware Tools,DisplayVersion; 9.0.10.29005
```